# Creating a Parse.File with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've followed the letter of the law (Javscript SDK) along with numerous variations but thus far I have not been able to save an image to a Parse.File.  I'm starting think this is code they never finished before they abandoned the platform?

This is my error:
Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.

This is my code:

```
var base64 = $base64.encode(unescape(encodeURIComponent('a string')));
var file = new Parse.File("logo.png", { base64: base64});
file.save().then(function(){
    var newLogo = new Parse.File();
    newLogo.set('step2.png', file);
    newLogo.save().then(function(){
        offer.set("Alogo.png", newLogo);
        offer.save();
    }).then(function(){}, function(error){console.log(error);});
});
```

It saves no image or note of 'Alogo.png' or anything dealing with a logo in my ParseDB. Any help you could offer would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error is happening here: `var newLogo = new Parse.File();`. The error says clearly that this constructor expects two arguments and you are passing it zero. Where is the example code for which you are following the letter of the law?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#files

Please, tell me where I'm going wrong. Parse documentation has me so frustrated . . .

Comment: I've never used parse myself, but I had a quick look through the documentation. You always need to pass at least 2 arguments to `Parse.File()`, the file name and the file data. What are you trying to do with `newLogo` here - make another `Parse.File` with a different name? (You're trying to call `.set()`, but that looks like a function you can only use with `Parse.Object`). If so, have you tried `var newLogo = new Parse.File('step2.png', {base64: base64});`? Same question applies to `offer`, though it's also not defined in this snippet of code.

Comment: According to the documentation I saw you must save the Parse.File first then after that you can set its association with a Parse.Object, which is what I'm using 'set' for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once, Parse was right on point.  The issue was not with my code but with Angular and it's lack of recognition of 'file' tags in html.  This post/tutorial proved very useful as it has a directive that enables angular to recognize post tags so that angular can add files to the model.

http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs