# How do you save an image file with html/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, parse-platform, save

I want to allow a user to save an image on one page/state of my app and then programmatically call that image on a different page/state of my app.  I considered three approaches thus far for saving the image but none of them seem to be working for me:

First I tried creating a 'Parse.File' with my chosen database, Parse.  Parse.File is how you save images.  For whatever reason, I've not been able to get this to work ([Creating a Parse.File with Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986701/creating-a-parse-file-with-javascript-sdk?noredirect=1#comment46230408_28986701)).  Parse's documentation is deceptively challenging as they presume more knowledge than I have.

Next I thought of saving images in the cloud and then just pointing to them in html. I tried Cloudinary but it took way to long just to figure how to assemble their Angularjs plugin and then it was missing any sort of documentation on how to actually execute anything meaningful.  Afterward I considered Flickr, which was much easier to get started but again they were missing an example I could easily apply to my basic case.

Finally, it occurred to me that maybe I could just save the image in a local directory with a matching reference in the database like any other asset I might call for my app.  Thus far I've not been able to figure out how to do this. I started trying to upload the image with $http. It didn't work so I looked into ng-file-upload and ngStorage.  Neither one has good application examples or great documentation. Finally, I tried this tutorial but got the dreaded Access Control Allow Origin error. Moreover, it's not clear to me which, if either is the right solution for this problem.

I'm not sure if any of these are the right approach.  Please share with me which approach is the one will work to allow a user to save an image file that can later be called.  If any of the aforementioned approaches work, please add some detail that may allow me to progress.

Comment: The PFFile ought to work.  Maybe post the pertinent code for that attempt.  What's the source of the file?

Comment: The issue wasn't with Parse.File, it was with the fact that Angular doesn't recognize the 'file' tag from html with a helper directive.  That can be found here: http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs and more explanation of my findings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986701/creating-a-parse-file-with-javascript-sdk?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an application or a website ?
I agree with you the documentation is very deceptively.

You can check these links:

- https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api
- http://www.antvox.com/index.php/articles/programming/10-uploading-files-to-parse-com-with-angularjs

---

I share my code for an application with cordova:

```
var photo;

var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: 0,
    encodingType: 0,
    targetWidth: 800,
    targetHeight: 800,
    mediaType: 0,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};

$scope.takePicture = function() {
    cameraOptions.sourceType = 1;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
}

$scope.selectPicture = function() {
    cameraOptions.sourceType = 0;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
}

function onSuccess(picture) {
    File.upload(picture)
        .success(function(data) {
            // What you want
        });
}

function onFail(resp) {
    alert('Error: ' + resp);
}
```